# Unable view the attachment saved as pdf Blob

Tags: attachment, pdf, blob.topdf

I'm getting a base64 String pdfContent from a callout response which I'm trying to save as a attachment of a record.
I tried to save it after decoding it with

`EncodingUtil.base64Decode('base64String');` - **Didn't work**

Tried to simply store it as Blob with

`Blob.valueOf('base64String');` - **Didn't work**

The Blob is getting saved as attachment But When I try to view it, It throws an Error

> "Failed to load Pdf Document"

How can I make it view-able?

Here's the apex logic of storing the attachment.

```
String base64String = 'some base64 String';
    Attachment atc = new Attachment();
    atc.Name = 'Test.pdf';
    atc.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
    //atc.Body = Blob.valueOf(base64String);
    //atc.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64String);
    //atc.ParentId = 'a0041XXXXXXXXXX';
    insert atc;
```

Comment: EncodingUtil.base64Decode  ... should work....may be input blob is faulty..

Comment: Cheked the blob..It's missing some part..
Now  EncodingUtil.base64Decode(); Worked

Answer (score 1):

Just adding as answer so that can help others:

Base64 input string was not complete and was causing faulty input blob.

After fixing it, EncodingUtil.base64Decode worked as expected.